# operator overloading >> and private member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cin, private-members, friend-function

Please do read before flagging as a duplicate

I am overloading operators >> and << for reading complex numbers with real part r and imaginary part i;

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
class complex
{
    int r,i;
public:
complex()
{ i=r=0;}
friend istream& operator>>(istream&, complex&);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,complex&);
};
istream& operator>>(ifstream &din, complex &x)
{
    din>>x.r;
    din>>x.i;
    return din;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &dout, complex &x)
{
dout<<x.r<<x.i;
return dout;
}
void main()
{
clrscr();
complex x;
cin>>x;
cout<<x;

}
```

The error is that r and i are not accessible
at code part

`din>>x.r;
din>>x.i;`

The error is that r and i are private so not accessible
Aren't normal friend functions able to access private variables. Why does it fail for >> only?

Note: << operator works fine. only >> fails

Comment: Please don't design your class in this way. It will be so confusing.

Comment: `iostream.h` is not a standard header. Use `iostream`. None of the standard C++ headers have extensions. `void main` is also not a legal signature. Use `int main`.

Answer (score 6):

The friend declaration of `operator>>` takes an `istream` argument, but the implementation takes an `ifstream` argument, making it a completely different (and thus non-`friend`) function.  Remove the extra `f`, and it should work.